# SQL OPENQUERY does not work for Provider = INSQL

Tags: sql, linked-server, openquery, wonderware, historian

INSQL is linked server that uses INSQL provider (from Wonderware Historian)

Query `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(INSQL,' SELECT 1')` gives error as below:

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The OLE DB provider "INSQL" for linked server "INSQL" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
An error occurred while preparing the query " SELECT 1" for execution against OLE DB provider "INSQL" for linked server "INSQL".

The same query is executed with no issues for another linked server that points to the same SQL server but uses SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Linked server security and server options are configured in the same way for both

Can you pleas help finding root cause?

Comment: Can you get on to the actual SQL Server (not the client) and do some tests with the INSQL driver. Confirm you can do a test connect, use the INSQL client tools installed on the sql server to try running some queries. From your description it sounds like you don't have any working connection to INSQL at all.